# Change radio button on click action to submit the form- gravity forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a gravity form that has a few questions and utilizes sections and conditional logic. One selection is radio buttons which is either "yes" or "no". If no is clicked, conditional logic opens another section to continue and the standard submit button is displayed. Submit is hidden using conditional logic based on the user selecting no. If yes is clicked, I would like the form to submit then. So you don't see the submit button, on click action of the yes radio button would submit it. That is what I am trying to accomplish.

I have tried making the buttons with HTML and adding the submit code to it but you cannot use html with conditional logic. So I couldn't hide the section that opens when no is clicked or use conditional logic to hide the submit button until No is clicked. I tried adding some script in an html box above the radio buttons but it did not do anything.

```
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>  
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function() {   
   $('input[name=input_2]').change(function(){  
        $('form').submit();  
   });  
  });  
</script>
```

Appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Are you using the mutli-step functionality in this form?

Comment: Do you mean with pages? No. It’s just 2 sections. First section has radio buttons. One is yes, one is no. When they select no, conditionally another section opens and the submit button displays, along with a few more questions.  When they hit yes, I need the yes to act as a submit. Staying on the same page if possible. Thank you

Comment: Potential Duplicate - This thread should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50205672/8059267